# Append text field to last of multiple text fields with same ID

Tags: php, jquery

After adding a record, the user can go back and edit the records. If they inserted 3, there will be 3 text areas with different values. I want them to be able to click a button and add as many more text areas as possible. My issue is that when doing so, the new blank text area appears under the first text area, instead of the third one making it text area number 4. I have tried using jQuery 'last' but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group" id="branch">
    <label for="example_input_full_name">
    Branch/Outlet
    </label>
    <textarea class="form-control m-input" name="branch[]" rows="6"><?php echo sanitize($branches->outlet_name); ?></textarea><p></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( '#add-more' ).on('click', function() {
        var branch =    "<div class='form-group m-form__group' id='branch'>" +
                        "<label for='example_input_full_name'>" +
                        "Branch/Outlet" +
                        "</label>" +
                        "<textarea class='form-control m-input' name='branch[]' rows='6'></textarea>" +
                        "</div>";
        $( '#branch' ).last().append(branch);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't give same `id` to multiple element in HTML. So take a `div` as parent element which contains all the `textarea` inside it and appends the created `div` at last.

```js
$( '#add-more' ).on('click', function() {
    var branch = "<div class='form-group m-form__group'>" +
                 "<label for='example_input_full_name'>" +
                 "Branch/Outlet" +
                 "</label>" +
                 "<textarea class='form-control m-input' name='branch[]' rows='2'></textarea>" +
                 "</div>";
    $('#branch').append(branch);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add-more">Add New</button>
<div id="branch">
  <div class="form-group m-form__group">
      <label for="example_input_full_name">Branch/Outlet</label>
      <textarea class="form-control m-input" name="branch[]" rows="2"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```